# haskell using list type function

Tags: list, haskell, types, addition

Hi I'm trying to use list types in haskell.

I have the following types in my .hs file:

```
type Name = String
type PhoneNumber = Int
type Person = (Name, PhoneNumber)
type PhoneBook = [Person]
```

I'm looking to add the function

```
add::Person -> PhoneBook -> PhoneBook
add ........
```

that adds an entry to the phone book at the beginning of the list. Testing it would be done through the terminal

Comment: What's your question? This is quite broad. Are you just asking how to add to a list?

Comment: It's also quite trivial (`add = (:)`), unless you want to avoid adding a duplicate entry.

Comment: I'm looking to create a function which pretty much adds every PhoneBook entered to a beginning of a list.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivially the cons operator `(:)`

```
add :: Person -> PhoneBook -> PhoneBook
add = (:)
```

However I think you're abusing tuples here in `Person`. You should consider using a custom data type rather than a tuple in most cases. Using record syntax makes life easy for you:

```
data Person = Person { getName        :: Name
                     , getPhoneNumber :: PhoneNumber }
```

Comment: Minor nit: a tuple *is* a product type, and necessary if one wants to treat `PhoneBook` as an association list for use with functions like `lookup :: a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b`.

Comment: @chepner how would I better-define that, then? "You should be using an *explicit* product type" or etc?

Comment: @ronevans I think you can figure that out -- try something yourself and ask if you can't come up with the answer after some effort.

Comment: I would just call it a custom data type. However, in this case, I think a simple tuple is the right choice, at least in the sense that a `PhoneBook` is mapping of names to numbers, rather than a collection of people.

Comment: @AdamSmith I understand what you mean thank you. What if I wanted to view the list of entries of the PhoneBook? So I can actually add an entry using the function 'add'. Something like E.g. add a b = ... where a b take the input of the name and phone number from terminal

Comment: @ronevans Then you'll be muddling in the `IO` monad since you're taking input, so you'll stop having a `PhoneBook` and start having an `IO PhoneBook`. This is not as trivial as it is in most programming languages.